# How do I know which class has been difficult to learn for my multi-class model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, multi-class, multilabel

For a multi-class model, there are always chances that the model is learning one class's features more than the other. But how do I find  which class has been weakly learned? Please help.

Comment: Find the class that is poorly predicted by the model, for example, by finding the class with the largest loss values or highest error rates.

Comment: thanks, but how do I find the class with largest loss values? do having TP, FP, TN, FN values for each class play any role to the calculation? Or are there other straightforward methods? @Sycorax

Comment: Have a look at the confusion matrix and look for off-diagonal entries.

Comment: Compute the loss individually for each observation, then sum by class.

Comment: @cdalitz your answer did the job for me,  thank you.